# Running Wire from outside (sub-Panel) mounted to stucco to inside garage, how to do it by code?

Tags: garage, stucco

I have a sub panel outside the house on the exterior outside the garage, house is a modern stucco exterior in Cali. I want to punch through the back of the panel and run some wires for an EV charger to the garage inside which has drywall interior.

1. When I pop out the cover in the panel what do i need to use behind the panel to seal it since it is flush against the wall? I can't use a water tight conduit fitting it won't fit.
2. Depends on your response to question 1. Let's assume I find some fitting that sits flush, between the wall I assume I need to run flex conduit and can't have exposed wires obviously as these will be thicker gauge wires correct?

Lastly I will be pulling those wires through conduit once I get them in the garage safely and per code hopefully. But I need to figure out this first part and the rest is easy.

Comment: Do you have to go through the back? Out the bottom or the side is probably easier.

Comment: Pictures of the panel will help immensely. Also, are you sure there's enough overhead in the panel to support an EV charger? Here's a frame challenge: Instead of running directly out the back of the panel, run out the bottom, into a bit of conduit, then an LB and through the wall.

Comment: Yes there is enough overhead in the panel no problem, I'm not fast charging 10A max overnight is enough and saves battery over the long haul. As far as going through the bottom, yes that is an option, it looks much less cleaner doing that but certainly can be done. I was hoping to do a cleaner install within the box. Can you guys suggest the options of going in the box itself even for my own SA i'm curious. thanks